# Corda vault batch query by arbitrary indexed object property

Tags: corda

looking for help regarding queries.  if i'm looking for the latest `LinearState` of `SomeObjectState` by property `someProp` i can do the following:

```
private fun lookupBySomeProp(someProp: String) : List<StateAndRef<SomeObjectState>> {
  val generalCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
  val somePropIdx = builder { SomePersistentObject::someProp.equal(someProp) }
  val somePropQueryCriteria = VaultCustomQueryCriteria(somePropIdx)
  val queryCriteria = generalCriteria.and(somePropQueryCriteria)
  val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<SomeObjectState>(queryCriteria)
  // ... handle results here
}
```

how would i go about doing a single batch lookup for multiple `SomeObjectState` objects given a list of `someProp` identifiers?

```
private fun lookupBySomeProps(somePropList: List<String>) : List<StateAndRef<SomeObjectState>> {
  val generalCriteria = VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
  // how do i build efficiently build my bulk query?
}
```

i'm expecting to have to do something along the lines of the following in order return multiple states matching the list but have been have trouble properly implementing it

```
val somePropeIdx = builder { SomePersistentObject::someProp.in(somePropList) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html you can use `.in()` in your criteria among many other things:

- Binary logical (AND, OR)
- Comparison (LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL)
- Equality (EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL)
- Likeness (LIKE, NOT_LIKE)
- Nullability (IS_NULL, NOT_NULL)
- Collection based (IN, NOT_IN)
- Standard SQL-92 aggregate functions (SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, COUNT)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your query in the question didn't work is because how Corda has defined the `.in()` function.

You had:

```
val somePropeIdx = builder { SomePersistentObject::someProp.in(somePropList) }
```

Substituting `notIn` works fine:

```
val somePropeIdx = builder { SomePersistentObject::someProp.notIn(somePropList) }
```

However, in order to use `.in()` you have to include backticks.
So your query would be:

```
val somePropeIdx = builder { SomePersistentObject::someProp.`in`(somePropList) }
```

You can see this difference in definition in the [source here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.8/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/services/vault/QueryCriteriaUtils.kt#L283-L287).